# How to prove this question using Induction? I can't think of a way

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction

Assume $A_1$ to $A_m$ are **all** the subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ which do not contain any consecutive values. Also for each subset $A,$ $P(A)$  is the product of every member of $A.$ ($P(\emptyset)=1.$)

So, for example, if $n=3,$ you get

$$A_1=\emptyset, A_2=\{1\},A_2=\{2\}, A_3=\{3\}, A_4=\{1,3\}$$

Now prove:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m P(A_i)^2 =(n+1)!$$

This is the original question In Farsi (Persian) :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbqzH.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123529/discussion-on-question-by-danial-azimi-how-to-prove-this-question-using-inductio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Base Case $n=1$ we have $A_1, A_2 = \emptyset, \{1\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^mP(A_i)^2 = 1^2 + 1^2 = 2 = 2!=(1+1)!$.  Okay.

Just to cement this home let's try another $n=2$ then $A_1, A_2, A_3 = \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}$ and $\sum P(A_i)^2 = 1 + 1 + 4 = 6= 3!$.

For a somewhat more complex $n=3$ then $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5$ are $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\},\{1,3\}$ and $\sum P(A_i)^2 = 1 + 1+4 + 9 + 9 = 24 = 4!$.

Okay.....

Indcution.  Suppose for $n$ we have the result.  Now for $n+1$.  First thing we have to ask ourselves is: what new sets do we have?  We ahve subsets of $\{1,2,3,....,n, (n+1)\}$ and we already would have had all the subsets that didn't include $n+1$ so the only new subsets will have $n+1$.

As there can be no consecutive numbers these new sets can not have $n$.  But every set we had when we calculated $n-1$ can just have $n+1$ added to them and be a new set.

So.... if $A_1, .... A_{m_{n-1}}$ are the subsets of $\{1,2,3,....,n-1\}$ with no consecutive numbers.  And $A_1, ....., A_m$ are the subsets of $\{1,2,3,.....,n\}$ with no consectutive numbers.  Then the *new* sets that include $n+1$ (but not $n$) are $A_{m+1} ,......., A_{m_{n+1}} = (A_1\cup \{n+1\}, A_2\cup \{n+1\}....., A_{m_{n-1}}\cup \{n+1\})$

And $\sum_{i=1}^{m_{n+1}} P(A_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{m} P(A_i)^2 + \sum_{i=m+1}^{m_{n+1}} P(A_i)^2=$

$(n+1)! + \sum_{i=1}^{m_{n-1}} [P(A_i)\cdot(n+1)]^2=$

$(n+1)! + (n+1)^2\sum_{i=1}^{m_{n-1}}P(A_i)^2 =$

$(n+1)! + (n+1)^2(n-1 + 1)!=$

$(n+1)! + (n+1)^2n! = $

$n![(n+1) + (n+1)^2]=$

$n![(n+1)\{1 + (n+1)\}]=$

$n!(n+1)(n+2) = (n+2)!$.

I'm.... surprised!  But that was fun.

.....

Note as the induction step used assuming the statment is true for $n$ *AND* also assuming the statement is true for $n-1$ we must use *strong* induction (where we don't just assume the statement is true for $n$ but is true for all $k \le n$) and as or induction case uses *two* early stages, we must have *two* base cases.

Base case 1: $n =1$.

Base case 2: $n = 2$.

Inductions step:  Whenever the statement is true for $n$ and $n-1$ it will be true for $n+1$.

Therefore it is true for all natural $n$.

Comment: How are you interpreting the question? As "there exists some $A_1,\dots,A_m$" so that this equality holds? And are you require the $A_i$ to be distinct?

Comment: I am interpretting it as "Let $U = \{A \subset\{1,2,3,4....,n\}| A$ contains no consecutive elements$\}$ and index them as $A_i;i = 1.......m$ where $m$ is whatever it has to be.  (I figure that $m = F_{n-1}$ BTW).  As yes the $A_i$ *are* distinct.  ANd they are exhaustive.  TBH I'm having a hard time seeing any *other* way to interpret the question.  .... And the statement *does* appear to be true and I believe my proof is sound.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. @fleablood

Comment: Fleablood, it is important that you read the new norm on math.se.  Please see math.meta [Enforcement of Quality-Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).